# bash scripting if statement, comparing decimal

Tags: bash, shell

Kind of new to bash scripting and is having trouble with the below code. 
I am trying to compare the array number with the number you have input from the "read ans" the problem is mostly comparing decimal numbers

```
    BGpercent=(0 99 99.3 99.6 99.8 100)
    BGpoint=(0 1 2 3 4 5) 
    read ans
    for (( c=${#BGpercent[@]}; c>=0; c-- ))
    do  
       echo "${BGpercent[$c]}"
        if [ "${BGpercent[$c]}" <= "$ans"  ];  
        then
        result=${BGpoint[$c]}
        break
        fi
    done
    echo $result | bc -lstrong text
```

**`Error - ./testscript.sh: =: No such file or directory`**

Comment: chmod 750 testscript.sh then try to launch it.  Also, add a shebang.

Comment: doesn't works, still having the same error

Comment: This part of the message `=:`  is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BGpercent=(0 99 99.3 99.6 99.8 100)
BGpoint=(0 1 2 3 4 5)

echo " Write in your number:"
read number

for (( c=${#BGpercent[@]}-1; c>-1; c-- ))
do
echo ${BGpercent[$c]}
bool=`echo "if (${BGpercent[$c]} <= ${number}) 1" | bc`
if [ "$bool"1 -eq 11 ] ; then
   result=${BGpoint[$c]}
   break
fi

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in your `if` check (floating point comparison).

```
#!/bin/bash

    BGpercent=(0 99 99.3 99.6 99.8 100)
    BGpoint=(0 1 2 3 4 5)
    read ans
    for (( c=$[ ${#BGpercent[@]} - 1 ] ; c>=0; c-- ))
    do
        if (( $(echo "${BGpercent[$c]} <= $ans" |bc -l) ));
        then
        result=${BGpoint[$c]}
        break
        fi
    done
```

Also, the variable `c` value must be decremented in the beginning, else it will contain an invalid index value. I am not sure what you intent to do with the last line (`echo $result | bc -lstrong text`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! now i am getting this error.
syntax error on line 1, teletype

Comment: Did you change the c variable initialization in the for loop as well? See this link: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/6996-syntax-error-line-1-teletype.html

Comment: @A.M.D, did you change this? `c=$[ ${#BGpercent[@]} - 1 `

Comment: @Thirupathi Thangavel : Yes i did